# Design an algorithm so as to destroy all enemy monsters in k or fewer turns

Tags: algorithms

> In a card, game opponent places $n$ monster cards onto the board, the $i$th of which has $h_i$ health points. You, in turn, have $m ≥ n$ hero cards in your hand, the $j$th of which deals $d_j$ damage per turn. To begin the game, you will choose $n$ heroes from your hand and assign each of them to a different enemy monster. Each turn, your heroes will deal damage equal to their damage power to the opposing enemy. If an opponent’s monster reaches 0 health or less, it is destroyed. You are given a limited number of turns $k$ to destroy
> all enemy monsters. Design an algorithm that determines whether it is possible to assign your heroes in such a way as to destroy all enemy monsters in $k$ turns or fewer.

**My Thoughts**
Each of the $n$ chosen heroes can kill exactly one monster. There is a one-to-one mapping
between the heroes and the monsters, and each of the $n$ chosen heroes fight their allocated
monster, dealing $d_j$ points of damage per turn. If all $n$ monsters are destroyed in $k$ turns
or fewer, the player wins. Otherwise, the player loses. Could there be a way to assign a hero
to the monster with the most health points?

Comment: If none of the heroes can destroy the healthiest monster, *it* is not possible. If one can, problem size is reduced by one.

Comment: @greybeard There is a touch of bin-packing involved here. Having the strongest hero hit the beafiest monster in all k rounds may not be the optimal action.

Comment: Can you do it for $k = 1$? Can you do it for $k = 2$?

Comment: Arno, it's optimal with the rules as described. One hero assigned to one monster and it cannot be changed. So the number of turns is irrelevant. Admittedly the rules look stupid to me. For example m >= n is pointless, since you will only ever use the n strongest heroes.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied text. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your question to bring it into compliance.